# Move cursor more smoothly (remote app)

Tags: java, android, client-server

I am writing Android remote app. When I touch and move on Android app, **the cursor on server machine moves too but it delays for about a second**.

My app simply are two threads: client sends coordinates, server receives them and that's all.
My solution is just to pass dx, dy through ObjectInputStream and use Robot::mouseMove to move the cursor.

**Can you give me some advices to prevent the cursor from delaying?** (smoothly like [RemoteDroid](http://www.remotedroid.net/) ^^)

My Sever:

```
    public void run() {         
            ..........
            while(true) {

                    // get dx, dy from ObjectInputStream
                    ........

                    moveMouseByDelta(dx, dy);
            }
            ...........
    }

    private void moveMouseByDelta(int dx, int dy)
    {
        try {
            Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
            int currentX = p.x;
            int currentY = p.y; 
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.mouseMove(currentX + dx, currentY + dy);              
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My Client (Android remote app):

```
private void touchTouchPad(MotionEvent event) 
{
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();
        switch(event.getAction()) {
           ............
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if(leftMouseHold) {
                    if(clientThread != null) {
                        int dx = x - xMouse;
                        int dy = y - yMouse;
                        xMouse += dx;
                        yMouse += dy;
                        clientThread.sendDelta(dx, dy);
                    }
                }
                break;
            ..............
        }
}
```

(This is not my homework, it is my study)

Edit: add more information

Comment: You didn't provide much of the client-server interaction code but if you didn't do it already, add `OutputStream.flush()` after you've written coordinates from client. Also it might be worth checking where that delay comes from, put System.out once you receive coordinates, etc, to hunt down if you can find place where it hangs.

Comment: Please explain the nature of the client-server communication channel.

Answer (score 1):

I speak only about Windows OS, this is nothing unusual, because RDP is limited to BW at 56-64Kb/per sec,

1 / freezing, slowdown and delay is caused by translation between resolution (in pixels between f.e. handy 480x320 and fullHD PC monitor) of both devices, if is the difference (in pixels) is greater, then the movement is more unnatural,

2 / freezing and delay is caused by fluctuations in the data connection

worst is when they are at the moment the two factors together, then it's decent fun